# LightSwitch hide delete button until record is selected

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and LightSwitch. I figured out how to create a delete record button and it works great. The only problem I have is on my main page where all records are shown.

When the page loads, The View & Edit buttons only appear once I select a record. the Add and Delete are visible all the time. The problem is, while the delete function works, it only works when a record is selected. So, if the page loads and you click delete it errors out. I would like to hide the delete button until a record is clicked on. By default the Edit and View buttons that Lightswitch creates do this, however since you have to write your own Delete function I have not figured out how to do this.

Here is an example of the C# i'm working with which works fine provided a record is selected..

```
myapp.BrowseGiftRegistries.DeleteRegistry_execute = function (screen) {
    screen.GiftRegistries.deleteSelected();
    return myapp.commitChanges().then(null, function fail(e) {
        myapp.cancelChanges();
        throw e;
    });
};
```

Comment: Please edit the tag. I believe its c# not c

Answer (score 2):

In the delete button's _canExecute() method just put the following code:

```
myapp.MyScreen.DeleteButton_canExecute = function (screen) {
    return screen.GiftRegistries.selectedItem != null;
};
```

You can also control whether the button is visible when disabled by checking or unchecking the "Hidden if disabled" checkbox in the properties for the selected button.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it on client side using javascript(it seems that you have provided javascript code).

For example, if you have delete button named 'DeleteRegistry':

Add code below to your *BrowseGiftRegistries.lsml.js*

```
myapp.BrowseGiftRegistries.created = function (screen) {
    screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isEnabled = false;
    //screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isVisible = false;
};

// Function created by clicking List( Gift Registries)->properties window->
// ->Actions->Item tap->None->edit execute code

myapp.BrowseGiftRegistries.GiftRegistry_ItemTap_execute = function (screen) {
   screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isEnabled = true;
   //screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isVisible = true;
};

// Modification of your function
myapp.BrowseGiftRegistries.DeleteRegistry_execute = function (screen) {
    screen.GiftRegistries.deleteSelected();

    screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isEnabled = false;
    //screen.findContentItem('DeleteRegistry').isVisible = false;

    return myapp.commitChanges().then(null, function fail(e) {
        myapp.cancelChanges();
        throw e;
    });
};
```

You can replace line containing isEnabled field with commented line containing isVisible field to reach result you need.